# Center of gravity of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I think the center of gravity of an ellipse is the intersection point of it's two radius.
But I didn't see it anywhere, so I'm having some doubt about it.

Am I right?

Thanks to all.

Comment: It is right in the middle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.  The axes (they are not usually called radii) are axes of symmetry, so the CG has to be along them.